# How to pass a list of lists when navigating?

Tags: android, kotlin, arguments, android-navigation

I have a list that contains lists like below

```
val asd:MutableList<List<String>> = mutableListOf(listOf("a","b","c"),listOf("d","e","f"))
```

I want to pass `asd` when I'm navigating to another fragment, but it seems like there's no list of lists arg type in `navigation.xml`. I only found list of element arg type like below

```
<argument
    android:name="getAnswerListFromGameFragment"
    app:argType="string[]" />
```

Does anyone knows how to pass list of lists when navigating?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs (https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data) it seems that lists of lists aren't a supported argument type, you should pass a custom class you create for this purpose.